# Store Global Data Android App With Service

Tags: singleton, global-variables, android-sqlite, android

I have an android app that consists of several activities / fragments and one service.  In one of the activities I create a new variable which I need to access from most of the other activities and the service.  What is the best way to handle this so that even if the app is closed and reopened the value persists.  Currently I pass the variable to my service and then each activity has to use a Messenger to query the service and get the value back.  I am wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this that doesn't require that each activity bind to the service to get the one value.

Possible Solutions:
1. Singleton - Will this survive the app being closed?
2. Extending Application and storing the value there - Seems like this is discouraged especially for such a simple use case.
3. Database the field locally and then just query it when needed, might be ok but might also be overkill.
4. Combination of 1 and 3 where I have a singleton which returns the value if it has it and if it doesn't then it will query the db and get the value.  This way the db only has to be queried once as long as the app is running and the value will be persisted through app closes.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Nathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Singleton - Will this survive the app being closed?

It will live as long as your process lives.

> Extending Application and storing the value there - Seems like this is discouraged especially for such a simple use case.

It adds no value over the singleton option in this case.

> Database the field locally and then just query it when needed, might be ok but might also be overkill

If you need the data to survive your process being terminated, you will want to persist it somehow (database, file, `SharedPreferences`). However, your option 4 (using a singleton cache) will be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  After looking into the shared preferences class I think that might be the best route since I just want to save a string.  I initially overlooked it because I thought it was only for saving app settings but looks like this might be a good match.

Comment: @Nath5: While `SharedPreferences`' sweet spot is for user settings, plenty of developers have used it for lightweight storage of other bits of data.